# Why is custom SerDe ignored by the Kafka Streams application (Spring Cloud Stream)?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

So I have implemented a custom SerDe that extends from `SpecificAvroSerde` provided by Confluent to attempt a retry whenever there is a timeout communicating with the Schema Registry. I've configured the Spring Cloud Streams Kafka binders to use it as default:

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.default.key.serde=com.test.RetrySpecificAvroSerde
```

Today I saw this error in the logs:

```
2020-12-14 01:31:53.006 ERROR 1 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.p.internals.StreamThread         : stream-thread [de7ait1214-x07-baseline-pc-data-s
torage-earning-factors-3bb21ce3-c620-4e6b-8cd2-00059a5c6326-StreamThread-1] Encountered the following unexpected Kafka exception during processing, this usually indicate Streams internal errors:

org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: stream-thread [de7ait1214-x07-baseline-pc-data-storage-earning-factors-3bb21ce3-c620-4e6b-8cd2-00059a5c6326-StreamThread-1] task [0_0] Exception caught while punctuating processor 'KSTREAM-TRANSFORM-0000000001'
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.punctuate(StreamTask.java:449) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.0.jar:na]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.PunctuationQueue.mayPunctuate(PunctuationQueue.java:54) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.0.jar:na]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.maybePunctuateSystemTime(StreamTask.java:868) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.0.jar:na]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AssignedStreamsTasks.punctuate(AssignedStreamsTasks.java:502) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.0.jar:na]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.punctuate(TaskManager.java:557) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.0.jar:na]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.maybePunctuate(StreamThread.java:951) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.0.jar:na]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:823) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.0.jar:na]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:697) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.0.jar:na]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:670) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.0.jar:na]
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error registering Avro schema: {...avro json...}
Caused by: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException: Register operation timed out; error code: 50002
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.sendHttpRequest(RestService.java:236) ~[kafka-schema-registry-client-5.3.3.jar:na]
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.httpRequest(RestService.java:265) ~[kafka-schema-registry-client-5.3.3.jar:na]
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.registerSchema(RestService.java:365) ~[kafka-schema-registry-client-5.3.3.ja
r:na]
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.registerSchema(RestService.java:357) ~[kafka-schema-registry-client-5.3.3.ja
r:na]
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.registerSchema(RestService.java:343) ~[kafka-schema-registry-client-5.3.3.jar:na]
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.registerAndGetId(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:168) ~[kafka-schema-registry-client-5.3.3.jar:na]
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.register(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:222) ~[kafka-schema-registry-client-5.3.3.jar:na]
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.register(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:198) ~[kafka-schema-registry-client-5.3.3.jar:na]
        at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.serializeImpl(AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.java:70) ~[kafka-avro-serializer-5.3.3.jar:na]
        at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer.serialize(KafkaAvroSerializer.java:53) ~[kafka-avro-serializer-5.3.3.jar:na]
        at io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.SpecificAvroSerializer.serialize(SpecificAvroSerializer.java:65) ~[kafka-streams-avro-serde-5.3.3.jar:na]
        at io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.SpecificAvroSerializer.serialize(SpecificAvroSerializer.java:38) ~[kafka-streams-avro-serde-5.3.3.jar:na]
        at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer.serialize(Serializer.java:62) ~[kafka-clients-2.5.0.jar:na]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl.send(RecordCollectorImpl.java:175) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.0.jar:na]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl.send(RecordCollectorImpl.java:111) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.0.jar:na]
...
```

This tells me that the SerDe used by Kafka Streams is not the one I defined above but rather the base class `SpecificAvroSerde` (which wraps `SpecificAvroSerializer`).

Is this related to some way Spring Cloud Stream Kafka library tries to auto-infer the SerDe to use? What is the "correct" way of overriding and setting the SerDe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see this in your config: `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.default.key.serde`.
That is the default key `Serde`. Did you mean to use it as `value.serde`. Then, that needs to be changed.

With that said, you can set the `Serde` on the individual binding as well (which has higher precedence).

You can also define a bean of type `RetrySpecificAvroSerde` in your applications, if your Kafka Streams function is strongly typed (i.e. `KStream` generic arguments are using the correct type). This method has the highest precedence in the binder.

After correcting it, if it still fails, please share with us a small sample, then we can take a look.

Comment: In fact it turned out the issue was more about the way the custom Serde was implemented. Because it extended SpecificAvroSerde and not all methods were overridden, as some point a wrong instance was returned (SpecificAvroSerializer instead of RetrySpecificAvroSerializer). I think the default.key.serde config setting worked fine in this case. I would leave the question open because your answer provides some helpful general hints around this topc (if OK with the community).